# Pandas reset multilevel index order

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have below dataframe, index are `Letter and Color`

```
                       Value
Letter Color Number       
a      Red   1          97
       Green 1          61
b      Red   1          97
       Green 1          98
c      Red   1          91
       Green 1          47
```

I'm trying to convert it into below,

```
                      Value
Letter Color Number       
a      Red   1          97
       Green 1          61
c      Red   1          91
       Green 1          47
b      Red   1          97
       Green 1          98
```

So far I've tried `reorder_levels()` but not work as it only swap position between Letter and Color. What I want to achieve is to swap position between index `a,b,c`. Can anyone give a hint.

Comment: Can you reindex? `df.reindex(['a', 'c', 'b'], level=0)`?

Comment: works perfect! thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try with `argsort` when change to `Categorical`

```
df = df.iloc[pd.Categorical(df.index.get_level_values(0),['a','c','b']).argsort()]
Out[191]: 
                     Value
Letter Color Number       
a      Red   1          97
       Green 1          61
c      Red   1          91
       Green 1          47
b      Red   1          97
       Green 1          98
```